# Salesforce report (for leads) fields not syncing with marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, sales-cloud, sync, data-import

Have created a report for leads in sales cloud. It creates the report with 9 fields only whereas there are some 60 fields in the leads. If I import this report in marketing cloud, I am able to do so, however if I add more fields (by dragging) in the report (in sales cloud) and then try to import in marketing cloud, it fails.